# how to loop through nested 'div' elements using cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to modify each `<div>` element in my HTML by wrapping it with new lines using cheerio.

input:

```html
<html>
    <body> 
        <div>
            <div><div>Hi</div></div>
            <div>hello</div>
            <div>ur awesome</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Expected output:

```html
<html>
    <body> 

        <div>

            <div>

                <div>Hi</div>

            </div>


            <div>hello</div>


            <div>ur awesome</div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

the output I got:

```html
<html><head></head><body> 
        
 <div>
            <div><div>Hi</div></div>
            <div>hello</div>
            <div>ur awesome</div>
        </div> 

    
</body></html>
```

**Problem**: It is not adding the new lines to the nested `<div>` elements. Tried using `$(this)` context but did not work.

**code**:

```js
const c = require('cheerio')
const $ = c.load(html);

$('div').each((i,e) => {
    let mod = `\n ${ c.html($(e)) } \n`
    $(e).replaceWith(mod)
})

console.log($.html())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('div').before("\n").after("\n")
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. I didn't know we can do it without looping :-)